How to give edit access to certain users for ''File Privacy on Records'' field in content version object
I need to give edit access to certain users for ''File Privacy on Records'' field in content version object but in permission set i couldnt find the object content version and even in field level there is no option to set field level access.

Can you try to update field 'SharingPrivacy' on ContentVersion (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)
